# Bug in Bootstrap carousel when click on next and back

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have integrated bootstrap carousel but when i click on next and prev it shows some bug. Can someone help me what am missing ?

here is the link of website http://logmak.justevent.in/ please check 4 product slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed a function that changes how `carousel` behaves by default, just after you initiate it. That's what's causing your problem.

A quickfix would be:

```
.item.next.left {
  display: none;
}
```

but there will be no transition from the old items to the new ones, at the end of the slide transition. My advice is to look for a carousel that allows you to set the `step` of the slide out of the box, such as [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

(Not endorsing it, feel free to look for better alternatives. I use it because it's easy to style and quite small, pefect for my own needs. Your needs might be different.)

Comment: yeah you are right,after putting this code its not showing that bug. by the way when i show 6 products in line it works fine but when i put 4 products then i give problems.